# Create a new categorical column based on conditions of values in other columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, categorical-data

Although it might seem it has been previously solved [in other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669111/create-new-column-based-on-condition-on-other-categorical-column), my problem is a little bit more challenging.

Let's start with an example I copied/pasted from a Calc sheet:

[image]

This is the minimal reproducible example required:

```
Label <- c("Catalog codes:" , "Themes:", "Size:", "Score:", "Buy Now:",
           "Series:", "Catalog codes:", "Themes:", "Related items:", "Buy Now:",
           "Catalog codes:", "Themes:", "Size:", "Score:",
           "Series:", "Themes:", "Size:", "Score:", "Related items:",
           "Catalog codes:", "Themes", "Size:", "Score:", "Related items:", "Buy Now:")
example <- as.data.frame(Label)
```

Part of the R dataframe I have contains a column with such column (`Label`) and many many rows.

The point here is that a group of rows belongs to one category (let's say `Group 1` and so on). You can identify the different groups in pink and white background in the previous image.

Although there is an **inner order** of the labels in each group, **not all the groups contain the same labels**.

However, the **starting and ending labels in each group remains the same**, depending on the label which is present. You can see that `Catalog codes:` and `Series:` start each group, whereas `Buy Now:`, `Score:` and `Related items:` end each group.

I would like to create a second column in this dataframe which could identify the patterns or combinations of these ending/starting labels, and later on, categorize them. The result might be similar to this image:

[image]

Comment: Please do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead. Also it's way easier to help you if you give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: I added the code of the data frame example @dario

Comment: You say `Catatolg codes` and `Series` both start a new group... But in your sample output, row 6(Series) row 7 (Catalog Codes) are in tyhe same group... Why?

Comment: @Wimpel, because I mentioned that not all the labels are present in a group. In the example you cited, Group 2 has both labels, but the others don't. When Series: is, present, Series: is the first label. When it is absent, the first is the next one, which is Catalog codes:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for the starting labels and the ending labels with `grepl()`, you can shift the ending label for one row and see where the starting and ending labels match and use that to create your group id with `cumsum()`. This ensures that you always group everything between the first starting label of a group and the last ending label of a group together since there can be multiple labels in a group.

```
Label <- c("Catalog codes:" , "Themes:", "Size:", "Score:", "Buy Now:",
           "Series:", "Catalog codes:", "Themes:", "Related items:", "Buy Now:",
           "Catalog codes:", "Themes:", "Size:", "Score:",
           "Series:", "Themes:", "Size:", "Score:", "Related items:",
           "Catalog codes:", "Themes", "Size:", "Score:", "Related items:", "Buy Now:")
example <- as.data.frame(Label)


example$Group <- paste("Group", 
                       cumsum(
                         grepl("Catalog codes:|Series:", example$Label) * c(TRUE, head(grepl("Buy Now:|Score:|Related items:", example$Label), -1))
                       )
)

# Result
            Label   Group
1  Catalog codes: Group 1
2         Themes: Group 1
3           Size: Group 1
4          Score: Group 1
5        Buy Now: Group 1
6         Series: Group 2
7  Catalog codes: Group 2
8         Themes: Group 2
9  Related items: Group 2
10       Buy Now: Group 2
11 Catalog codes: Group 3
12        Themes: Group 3
13          Size: Group 3
14         Score: Group 3
15        Series: Group 4
16        Themes: Group 4
17          Size: Group 4
18         Score: Group 4
19 Related items: Group 4
20 Catalog codes: Group 5
21         Themes Group 5
22          Size: Group 5
23         Score: Group 5
24 Related items: Group 5
25       Buy Now: Group 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not complete match your desired output... see output below...
Please clarify why row 6 does not have it's 'own' group, as asked in comments.

```
library( data.table )
setDT(example)[, Group := paste0( "Group ", 
                                  cumsum( grepl( "^Catalog codes|^Series", Label ) ) 
                                  ) ]
#              Label   Group
#  1: Catalog codes: Group 1
#  2:        Themes: Group 1
#  3:          Size: Group 1
#  4:         Score: Group 1
#  5:       Buy Now: Group 1
#  6:        Series: Group 2   <-- !!
#  7: Catalog codes: Group 3   <-- !!
#  8:        Themes: Group 3
#  9: Related items: Group 3
# 10:       Buy Now: Group 3
# 11: Catalog codes: Group 4
# 12:        Themes: Group 4
# 13:          Size: Group 4
# 14:         Score: Group 4
# 15:        Series: Group 5
# 16:        Themes: Group 5
# 17:          Size: Group 5
# 18:         Score: Group 5
# 19: Related items: Group 5
# 20: Catalog codes: Group 6
# 21:         Themes Group 6
# 22:          Size: Group 6
# 23:         Score: Group 6
# 24: Related items: Group 6
# 25:       Buy Now: Group 6
# Label   Group
```

Comment: I answered the question in the comments